# How do we know that light is massless?

Tags: visible-light, mass, speed-of-light

Almost everybody knows that light is massless. But where this come from and how it can be proven (experimentally or theoretically)? I actually found [this article](http://open.salon.com/blog/kwatts59/2009/02/18/physics_what_is_the_mass_of_light) which explains and calculates the mass of light at rest (which is not 0). So how do we know that light is massless?

Comment: The 'article' confuses relativistic mass and rest mass. Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4700/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

The [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/why-cant-photons-have-a-mass) link has good answers.

The experimental proof comes from fitting decays where photons are involved. For example the pi_0 decays into two photons. If these had a mass the energies would not balance in the fits.

[Pair production](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) would also be problematic, because a "massive photon" disappears into an electron positron pair in the field of a nucleus or an electron.  Photons have not been seen to decay in vacuum.

If the photon had a mass,it would have to be twice the mass of the electron in the photon   center of mass, not a negligible value , and energy  and momentum balances would never work.

All these arguments are encapsulated in the theoretical framework described in the answers to the duplicate question.