# Does light or waves have any kind of mass?

Tags: gravity, mass-energy

Just like the previous question,
 Even I have been studying Hawking's A Brief History Of Time and even I was thinking of Einstein's General Relativity. But I was unable to accept his view of GRAVITY. I have been working on a theory which needs that Gravity effects Light. And so my question is that, Is there any kind of mass for Light? as it was being effected by Gravity? 
  Excuse me if any mistakes were done.
  Plzz answer me.

Comment: E=m*c^2. So... yes.

Comment: Einstein's GR shows that light is affected by gravity and that light itself curves space as well

Comment: Light has no rest mass but it has a gravitational mass

Comment: @JanDvorak: [You may want to read this article](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4700)

Comment: @Hemanth: see also [How can gravity affect light](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130552/) and links therein

Answer (score 1):

No ,a photon has no mass but it (still)can have momentum 
according to the equation 
E^2=(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2 and yes,light can be effected by gravity because of its  energy(due to momentum )
simply you can say its not nessesary to have mass for a photon to be effected by gravity.