# Local Gauge Invariance and Masslessness

Tags: mass, classical-electrodynamics, gauge-invariance

I am wondering if the masslessness of photons is due to the local gauge invariance of $u(1)$-gauge fields. The reason why I consider about this question is that I remember that the [Proca field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proca_action) is not locally $u(1)$-invariant. How do I prove this explicitly in field theory?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4700/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi professor Qmechanic. Is professor Motl's answer also related with the mass gap of Yang-Mills fields?